# Setup indexing file in windows 8

Tags: windows-8

How can I setup file indexing in Windows 8 with the following critiria:

- It must index all files in all drives of my computer
- It must index the file name only and nothing else (not indexing content)

Please don't recommend any third-party application, as I want to search from the `Start Menu`, or use the `Windows + F` shortcut

Comment: You will have to modify the indexed locations to include all drives, and modify all advanced file type indexing settings to index properties only and not contents as well.

Comment: is there a faster way? having to change all file types one by one manually sounds..intimidating

Comment: Problem is, you can't even multi-select file types in that dialog. There *might* be an automated way of changing the setting for all file types, but it has to be done one way or another since you want to index all names and no contents.

Comment: Maybe if we knew where the settings are stored for a specific file type, we can automate it. Unfortunately [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/281966/how-to-back-up-windows-7s-indexing-options-settings) was never answered. Hopefully someone with free time and Process Monitor or similar tools can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to find file names, I recommend [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/). It's a search tool that reads the file names directly off of your hard drive's "address book". It's super fast and lightweight.

Comment: I want to find files from the start screen, not from a third party app